# Interrupting linux boot sequence in order to check if a license file exists else prompt for activation key

Tags: linux, license, systemd

Is there a some proper methodology to stop a user from booting into the shell or the GUI if a license file ( simply any file present on the disk) is not present? if a license file is not found the user is prompted for an activation key which if he fails to provide will result in the reboot of the system.

i tried writing init scripts which however turned out being unable to write to stdout, and i am also not sure if i could get any input from the user at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a `systemd` system you probably should use a `systemd` service, not an init script. Example code can be found in various RedHat (or here Centos) `initial-setup*` packages:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep initial-setup
initial-setup-gui-0.3.9.40-1.el7.centos.x86_64
initial-setup-0.3.9.40-1.el7.centos.x86_64
$ rpm -qi initial-setup | tail -2
The initial-setup utility runs after installation.  It guides the user through
a series of steps that allows for easier configuration of the machine.
$
```

You'll have to dig through the code to see what they do, but these packages do interrupt the normal boot to ask the user things.

Comment: i am trying to do this to a kali installation... any insights?